# Simple question about splitting fields

Tags: field-theory

Let f(x) be a polynomial in F[x]. Let K be the splitting field of f over F.

Let a be an element of F. Is K also the splitting field of (x-a)f(x)? I think it should be.
I just want to make sure I'm not being stupid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right.
 The splitting field of $f\in F[x]$ is the field obtained by adjoining all the roots of $f$ to $F$, the roots of $(x-a)f$ are just the roots of $f$ together with $a$ (if it wasn't one already), and adjoining $a$ does nothing because it's already in $F$. Thus, the splitting field of $(x-a)f$ is the same as the splitting field of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if your polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ is separable (say for example, $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, where $g(x), h(x) \in F[x]$), then the splitting field of $f(x)$ is the composite field of the splitting fields of the factors into which $f(x)$ separates (so the composite of the splitting fields for $g(x)$ and $h(x)$). Since in this case the splitting field of $x-a$ over $F$ is just $F$, and $F \subset K$, $FK = K$ is the splitting field of $(x-a)f(x)$.